# Eigenvalues of Polynomial of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I Believe to have found a counterexample to the following statement which i am being asked to prove.

Let T be a linear operator on a complex vector space V. Let p $\in P(C)$ be a polynomial and $ \alpha \in C$.Prove that $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of p(T) if and only if $\alpha = p(\lambda)$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of T.

Suppose $p(x) = a_0 x$
which means

$p(T) := a_0 I$

Then for T(x) = 5x the only eigenvalue is 5. The only eigenvalue of p(T) is $a_0$. For $a_0 = 3$ the statement would not hold since $\alpha = 3 \neq 15=p(5)= p(\lambda)$. Is this a correct counterexample? I do highly doubt it myself since this is a question in a popular linear algebra textbook

Comment: what is $p(T)$?

Comment: Your counterexample doesn't work : if $p(x)=ax$, then $p(T)=aT$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what a polynomial *in an operator* means.  So here's how it works:

Let $$p(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x+a_0$$ be a formal polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb F$.  Then for any endomorphism (a linear operator from a space to itself) $T$, $$p(T) = a_n (\underbrace{T\circ \cdots \circ T}_{n\text{ times}}) + a_{n-1} (\underbrace{T\circ \cdots \circ T}_{n-1\text{ times}}) + \cdots + a_1T + a_0\textrm{id}$$

Notice that this is an endomorphism as well because the sum, scalar multiple, and composition of linear operators is linear.

---

So in your example $p(T) = a_0T$.

Comment: thanks for your effort, this helped.